# Pgpool Server Failover

Tags: postgresql, system-administration, failover, pgpool, node-pg-pool

In my on-premises setup for client's project, I have two servers of Pgpool: one having a Pgpool that routes requests from web application to Master or Slave PostgreSQL. The other pgpool server is the failover server. In case of primary server for Pgpool fails, the failover mechanism would pass control to secondary server of Pgpool. Once, primary Pgpool is up, the control would get reinstate. Due to some network challenges we are not able to implement KeepAlived (I have Cent OS installed in both pgpool servers).

Can some one help me with a failover script or way to acheive the same